# How to say that the usage of something is questionable due to already exisiting solutions?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For example, I have developed a software algorithm which does the needed behaviour, but already existiing solutions are better or already implemented. How can I describe my algorithm with a professional adjective, that says something like "useless but working", e.g in the following sentence:

> "It was shown that the algorithm does the needed thing. However, the
>   usage of it may be *GOOD-ADJECTIVE* due to already exisitng
>   alternatives implemented."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is obsolete when it works, but something else better is now available. In the case you cite, the chronology is reversed. Perhaps we should call such an item ‘obsolete upon arrival’.

Comment: Thank you, that word "obselete" just slipped out of my vocabulary and matches perfectly in my case

Comment: Or, as I have heard it stated, _built-in obsolence_.

Comment: @Nigel J: ‘built-in’ obsolescence is intentional, but the OP is evidently referring to an accidental occurrence. More to the point, something with ‘built-in’ obsolescence is not immediately obsolete upon completion, but only after a (more-or-less pre-determined) time, which may be YEARS away.

Comment: "deprecated" is another possibility.

Comment: @Xanne - in the software community "deprecated" is more likely used if a function was implemented in Version 1 and now a new function which does the same thing is implemented in Version 2, so one should not use the old function from Version 1, thus it is so called "deprecated"